# Add rows to each group in a dataframe to match a range and fill NA with previous value or zero

Tags: python, pandas, join

I need to add missing days (as integers) between rows for each group and then fill missing values in a `value`column.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'days':[0, 2, 3, 1, 3], 'group':['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'], 'value': [1.2, 2.3, 3.4, 0.2, 0.3]})
```

**Input:**

```
days    group   value
0        A       1.2
2        A       2.3
3        A       3.4
1        B       0.2
3        B       0.3
```

I'm stuck on the first step - adding rows if 0-3 is missing.
I tried so far to join a dataframe on a Series repeated for each group or to reindex a dataframe.

```
df = df.set_index('days')
df.reindex(pd.Series(range(4)))

ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

**Expected output:**

```
cons_days   days    group   value
0           0        A       1.2
1           NaN      A       1.2
2           2        A       2.3
3           3        A       3.4
0           NaN      B       0.0
1           1        B       0.2
2           NaN      B       0.2
3           3        B       0.3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do with `pivot` , then `reindex`

```
df.pivot(*df.columns).reindex(pd.Series(range(4))).reset_index().melt('index')
Out[222]: 
   index group  value
0      0     A    1.2
1      1     A    NaN
2      2     A    2.3
3      3     A    3.4
4      0     B    NaN
5      1     B    0.2
6      2     B    NaN
7      3     B    0.3
```

Update

```
df.pivot(*df.columns).reindex(pd.Series(range(4))).ffill().fillna(0).reset_index().melt('index')
Out[226]: 
   index group  value
0      0     A    1.2
1      1     A    1.2
2      2     A    2.3
3      3     A    3.4
4      0     B    0.0
5      1     B    0.2
6      2     B    0.2
7      3     B    0.3
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't even think about pivoting.

Comment: @Wen-Ben: his expected output has `NaN` in `days`. Yours has `NaN` in `value`. Does it mean additional step needed?

Comment: @Wen-Ben: is `NaN` in his expected output typo? Just asking because your update answer has no `NaN` at all while his expected output has some 'NaN'

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using groupby:

```
df = (df.set_index('days')
        .groupby('group')['value']
        .apply(lambda x: x.reindex(range(0, x.index.max() + 1)))
        .reset_index()
       )
```

```
  group days value
0   A   0   1.2
1   A   1   NaN
2   A   2   2.3
3   A   3   3.4
4   B   0   NaN
5   B   1   0.2
6   B   2   NaN
7   B   3   0.3
```

Update using @WeNYoBen's fill method:

```
df = (df.set_index('days')
        .groupby('group')['value']
        .apply(lambda x: x.reindex(range(0, x.index.max() + 1)).ffill().fillna(0))
        .reset_index()
)
```

```
  group days value
0   A   0   1.2
1   A   1   1.2
2   A   2   2.3
3   A   3   3.4
4   B   0   0.0
5   B   1   0.2
6   B   2   0.2
7   B   3   0.3
```